# R: Object not found within a function

Tags: r

I'm having some issue with my code, whenever I run the code the output is always comes back with an error saying "Object pv not found" can anyone help out? It'd be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
lo <- function(x, y)
 {
   for(i in 1:(y-1))
   {
     for(j in 1:length(x))
     {
       First = function (x)
       {if (i%%x[j] == 0) {pv <- cumsum(x)}}
     }
   }
   return(pv)
}
lo(6, 20)
```

Comment: You have quite a few problems with the function. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your inner loop goes from `1:length(x)`.

You are supplying `20` as x. The length of an object that contains one number is 1. Looping from 1 to 1 means 0 iterations. You never run `pv <- cumsum(x)` then. So `pv` isn't defined when you get to the return statement.